# Space between two-column text vanishes if there is only one section on the page

Tags: two-column

I have a latex file with twocolumn text (IEEE template). Now I have a section 1 (`\section{}`), where the text fills a complete page and the next section 2 starts on a new page automatically. But this leads to an error, where the space between the two text columns disappears (only on the page with section 1). If I shorten the text, so that the header of section 2 is included on the same page as section 1 the problem disappears. Or I could add a `\newpage` at the end of section 1 and the problem disappears. I have no idea what to do, not even knowing where to look for the problem. Any suggestions?

**Update MWE**

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a


\section{Cantilever}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
% No contents in figure necessary to show problem
%   \includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{img/dummy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)! Have you read the guidelines before posting? Posting well formatted questions will be useful for others and for you in getting more answers and more easily. I recommend you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that we could better understand what's going on and what part of the code is responsible for it.

Comment: You have no idea what to do but we have no idea what you have done. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}` and dummy text. We need to know what else you're doing. Post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: I added a MWE. The floatrow package seems to be related to the issue.

Comment: I still can't compile your code as is, because (1) `\maketitle` throws an error without a `\title` command and (2) obviously I don't have that image. However, when I just use a random image, and `\title{My title}`, I still can't reproduce the error. Can you put your `.log` file in some pastebin service?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to reproduce it using my own dummy text from the `lipsum` package. It does seem to be a bad interaction between `IEEEtran.cls` and  `floatrow.sty`. Adding a blank `\mbox{}` at the start of each section seems to help, but you end up with windows/orphans. `\let\oldsection\section\def\section{\mbox{}\oldsection}` I'll keep poking around.

Comment: @frablous I updated the MWE again (basically removing all the underfull \hbox log messages). I get the same behaviour even when using article instead of IEEEtran.

Comment: I was able to replicate the behavior (the `\includegraphics` line is not actually necessary for replication—I'll edit the post to take it out).

It appears that there's an incompatibility between floatrow (which is 13 years old) and the current LaTeX float mechanism. I suspect the simplest approach would be to not use floatrow if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the floatrow package. It hasn't been edited since 2008, so it may not be possible to contact the author (though there is an email address in the documentation).

However, by trial and error playing around with some of the source code in the package, the following, placed *after* `\begin{document}` seems to help:

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \@namedef{figure}{\killfloatstyle\def\@captype{figure}\FR@redefs
    \flrow@setlist{{figure}}%
    \columnwidth\columnwidth\edef\FBB@wd{\the\columnwidth}%
    \FRifFBOX\@@setframe\relax\@@FStrue\@float{figure}}%
\makeatother
```

This differs from what is in the package at the first and third occurrence of `\columnwidth`, with are `\textwidth` instead in the package.

However, it is possible that this may change other things in your document, as I haven't thoroughly tested this with a real project.